# Caching and invalidating cached Mono

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient

I'm running into an issue while trying to cache a `Mono` returned by a `WebClient`. The code is something like that:

```
public Mono<Token> authenticate() {
    return cachedTokenMono = cachedTokenMono
        .switchIfEmpty(
            Mono.defer(() -> 
                    getToken())
                    .cache(token ->
                               Duration.between(Instant.now(), token.getExpires().toInstant()),
                           (Throwable throwable) -> Duration.ZERO,
                           () -> Duration.ZERO));
}
```

The intention is that the `Mono` used to receive a `Token` is cached until the token expires. After the token expires, the cached `Mono` becomes empty and a new token is requested.
This works as expected, but unfortunately `switchIfEmpty()` does not actually "switch", it wraps the source `Mono` instead. As a result, this creates a memory leak as more and more wrapping `SwitchIfEmptyMono` are created.
What is the correct pattern in this case? Is there a way to substitute an empty `Mono` with a new one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```java
private final Mono<Token> authenticateMono = getToken()
            .cache(
                    token -> Duration.between(Instant.now(), token.getExpires().toInstant()),
                    throwable -> Duration.ZERO,
                    () -> Duration.ZERO)

public Mono<Token> authenticate() {
    return authenticateMono;
}
```

The idea is that you're returning the same caching `Mono<Token>` instance for each call to `authenticate()`.  The `.cache` operator ensures that the cached result is checked for each subscription.

Specifically:

- if a new subscription arrives and there is no cached value, then the cache operator will subscribe to the `Mono<Token>` returned from `getToken()` (which will trigger the token retrieval).
- if a value has been cached, and a new subscription arrives *before* the cache has timed out, then the cache operator will emit the cached value to the new subscriber
- if a value has been cached, and a new subscription arrives *after* the cache has timed out, then the cache operator will resubscribe to the `Mono<Token>` returned from `getToken()` (which will trigger the token re-retrieval).
- If the `Mono<Token>` returned from `getToken()` completes with an exception, then that exception won't be cached, and therefore will propagate, and the next subscription that arrives will re-trigger the token retrieval again

This all assumes that:

- `getToken()` does not do any work before a subscriber arrives
- `getToken()` retrieves the token for each subscriber
- you only want one active token for all subscribers

Also note, that depending on your use case, you might want to expire the token slightly before it's expiration date, to account for clock skew.  i.e. to preemptively retrieve a new token just before it actually expires to prevent returning a `Token` that will expire before the downstream has had an opportunity to use it.