# How to invalidate cached Mono?

Tags: java, project-reactor

Is there a way to invalidate cached Mono? Either manually or with some condition?

Here is my case:

```
private Mono<String> cachedMono;

public MyService() {
  this.cachedMono = cacheData()
      .cache(value -> Duration.ofHours(1), ex -> Duration.ZERO, () -> Duration.ZERO);
}

private Mono<String> cacheData() {
  return webClient.get()
      .uri("/api/data")
      .retrieve()
      .bodyToMono(String.class);
}

public Mono<String> retrieveData() {
  return cachedMono;
}
```

Everything is good and data is invalidating after 1 hour.
But what I want is to invalidate it once I receive a notification externally that data has been changed and I should refresh the cache.

```
public void dataHasBeenChangedNotification(String newData) {
  // how to update cache with the new data?
  // or at least force the cache to invalidate and not to wait 1 hour
}
```

Found a similar link [Caching and invalidating cached Mono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58867228/caching-and-invalidating-cached-mono) but this is not something I'm looking for.

Comment: You might be interested in https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/2324

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to force invalidation of the cached signal. However, there is an open issue as Phil Clay mentioned: https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/2324.

We're currently thinking about a widened scope for that operator, where one could either provide a predicate or get a hold of a `Disposable` to manually invalidate the cache.

This is not going to be immediately available, though we'd like to add that feature within the 3.4.x line.